# Why are changes that have already been merged now showing up as new changes?

Tags: git, github, merge

**Scenario for my question**

- I made some changes to several files in my machines cloned repo.
- Committed the changes and pushed them to my fork in GitHub.
- Opened a PR from my fork to my organisations fork and my changes were merged.

Next day

- Made some more changes to other files in my machines cloned repo.
- Committed those changes and pushed them to my fork.

Here's where my problem is

- I opened a PR from my fork to my organisations fork and my changes from this day appear, which is fine, however my changes from the other day that were already merged also show as new changes.

Pulling the MyOrganisation:examplebranch into my feature branch would fix it, however I can't do that because it contains a bunch of other changes that I can't contaminate my branch with. If you're wondering how I keep my stuff up to date I pull from the upstream integration branch, which also has an auto-merge into the MyOrganisation:examplebranch.

So the question is, why are changes that have already been merged into "MyOrganisation:examplebranch" showing up as new changes?

*Note: I have triple checked that I'm comparing the correct branches and that the changes are in fact in the "MyOrganisation:examplebranch" so it's definitely not either of those.*

Comment: Can you also compare the SHA1 of the merged commits match the new commits that show up again? If they are really the same commits, then they should have the same SHA1. If they have different SHA1, then they are not the same commits, and it's normal that they show up.